# fetch feeds/post from a facebook public page

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-fql, restfb

I am currently working on a requirement where in I need to fetch the feeds/post from a public page.I am using the following FQL to do so :-

example - SELECT message FROM stream where source_id = 40796308305
Here page_id = 40796308305 is for the coca cola fb page.

The above query returns me the top 20  posts made by other users of the page. It doesn't fetch the ones posted by the page moderator/admin.Which is what i am after.Please suggest where i am going wrong.I have searched on the internet but to no avail.any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your access token. The coca cola page should approve your app to have access to their stream. In that case you can get all their posts also. But if you use an access token which is not from coca cola approving your access to their stream, you can only access the page its followers their posts.